# How to define no upper limit in JavaFX's Spinner

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a numerical `Spinner`. I don't want to define a max value. The following code gives me an error because `Spinner(int min, int max, int initalValue)` does not accept null values.

```
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1, null, 1);
```

In Swing, I can pass null values for this, how would I do the same in JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Long story short, you can't!*

**Reasons**

1. The spinner is not designed to take **null** values. The spinner takes **primitive data types** as parameters and calls [SpinnerValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory.html) internally whose constructors, again, accept primitive data-types. *You can't pass null to primitive types.*
2. Even if you defined `Spinner spinner = new Spinner()`, you will have to use [setValueFactory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#setValueFactory-javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory-) for it to work.

**Solution**

Your best bet is to use [INTEGER.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) in case you are using a [SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory.html), which IMHO should be enough ;)

```
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1,Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
```

If you need even higher values go with [DoubleSpinnerValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This should have been a feature.

Comment: "No upper limit" is somewhat misleading though. If the value is represented by an integer, it can't possibly go beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and the results you would get if you tried would be unexpected and hard to debug. Better to explicitly state what the maximum storable value is.